# I want to get the total as revenues by subtracting the price from tbl_sales and the price from tbl_expenses, How can query this problem?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have this tables tbl_sales and tbl_expenses:

tbl_sales

| salesID | itemName | price | dateSold |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | soap | 20.00 | 06/11/20 |
| 2 | candy | 2.00 | 07/07/20 |
| 3 | beer | 63.00 | 08/07/20 |

tbl_expenses

| expenseID | items | price | dateBuy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | paper | 10.00 | 06/07/20 |
| 2 | pen | 5.00 | 07/11/20 |
| 3 | chalk | 2.00 | 08/07/20 |

I want to get this result:

| revenue | months |
| --- | --- |
| 10.00 | June |
| 3.00 | July |
| 61.00 | August |

`price - price = revenue` and date will convert to month names. How can I execute this in sql query?

I don't want to get a negative result for the revenue, if that happens the result will turn into positive even the expenses are much higher than the sales. What should I do about it ?

Comment: Hi @Omegalul you told revenue = price - price but according to your expected result value is sum up month wise.

Comment: I'm sorry I made a mistake when I first calculated the price, I edited the new one

Comment: why july value is 2 ?

Comment: Sorry sorry its 3, I didnt notice

Comment: But reveneu = salesprice - expenseprice; so for july it is 2-5 = -3. so as your expectation it will -3. as -3 < 0 so it will 0. why 3

Comment: Hi @Omegalul please provide your explanation then I'll give my answer. Otherwise not try to solve this.

Comment: Okay I'll correct that about negative to 0, how can I make it positive when the result is negative? that when expenses are higher than sales?

Comment: Sorry for the bad explanation sir, I rearranged my explanation so that you can better understand my problem, I hope you can still help me

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: And I still don't understand why we end up with 3 instead of minus 3

Comment: use sum difference  and group by month(date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per given table data INNER JOIN is suitable. Otherwise at this case FULL OUTER JOIN will perfect because if sales or expense missing any month then result will mismatch and use COALESCE() for eliminate NULL.

```
-- MySQL
SELECT s.month_name
     , CASE WHEN s.sales_price>= p.expense_price
               THEN (s.sales_price - p.expense_price)
            ELSE (p.expense_price - s.sales_price)
       END revenue
FROM (SELECT MONTHNAME(date_format(str_to_date(dateSold,'%m/%d/%Y'),'%Y%m%d')) month_name
           , SUM(price) sales_price
      FROM tbl_sales
      GROUP BY MONTHNAME(date_format(str_to_date(dateSold,'%m/%d/%Y'),'%Y%m%d'))) s
INNER JOIN (SELECT MONTHNAME(date_format(str_to_date(dateBuy,'%m/%d/%Y'),'%Y%m%d')) month_name
                 , SUM(price) expense_price
            FROM tbl_expenses
            GROUP BY MONTHNAME(date_format(str_to_date(dateBuy,'%m/%d/%Y'),'%Y%m%d'))) p
        ON s.month_name = p.month_name;
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=80441dc236aed62722b80f17fdfe88eb

Another solution:
Data retrieval by month wise ordering and check every possible combination of sales and expense. If both are negative then 0; otherwise if sales positive but expense negative then shows only sales value and same condition apply for expense also.

```
-- MySQL
SELECT s.month_name
     , CASE WHEN (s.sales_price >= 0 AND p.expense_price >= 0)
               THEN CASE WHEN s.sales_price >= p.expense_price
                            THEN (s.sales_price - p.expense_price)
                         ELSE (p.expense_price - s.sales_price)
                    END
            ELSE (CASE WHEN s.sales_price >= 0 AND p.expense_price < 0
                          THEN s.sales_price
                       WHEN p.expense_price >= 0 AND s.sales_price < 0
                          THEN p.expense_price
                       ELSE 0
                  END)
       END revenue
FROM (SELECT MONTH(date_format(str_to_date(dateSold,'%m/%d/%Y'),'%Y%m%d')) month_no
           , MAX(MONTHNAME(date_format(str_to_date(dateSold,'%m/%d/%Y'),'%Y%m%d'))) month_name
           , SUM(price) sales_price
      FROM tbl_sales
      GROUP BY MONTH(date_format(str_to_date(dateSold,'%m/%d/%Y'),'%Y%m%d'))) s
INNER JOIN (SELECT MONTH(date_format(str_to_date(dateBuy,'%m/%d/%Y'),'%Y%m%d')) month_no
                 , MAX(MONTHNAME(date_format(str_to_date(dateBuy,'%m/%d/%Y'),'%Y%m%d'))) month_name
                 , SUM(price) expense_price
            FROM tbl_expenses
            GROUP BY MONTH(date_format(str_to_date(dateBuy,'%m/%d/%Y'),'%Y%m%d'))) p
        ON s.month_no = p.month_no
ORDER BY s.month_no;
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e03891b8e88ce5b266ecf3adb4178d19

Comment: Hi @Omegalul please check my query and let me know if any query regard this.

Comment: Hi @Omegalul month wise ordering will work now. Thanks for accepting my answer. If this is useful for you then please mark this as useful along with accepted.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(A.extracted_month,'%m')) AS MONTHNAME, A.monthly_sale-B.monthly_expense AS Revenue FROM (SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date_sold) AS extracted_month, SUM(price) AS monthly_sale FROM sales GROUP BY extracted_month) AS A
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dateBuy) AS extracted_month, SUM(price) AS monthly_expense FROM expenses GROUP BY extracted_month) AS B ON A.extracted_month = B.extracted_month
```

Use Case statement if you want to show revenue as 0 for negative values.

Comment: @omegalul you can use "ORDER BY A.extracted_month" at the end of my query to sort the months in ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

If less typing and better performance are attractive propositions, then perhaps something like the following will suffice - although if revenue is calculated as expenditure minus sales, then I am extremely wealthy...

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl_sales;

CREATE TABLE tbl_sales
(salesID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,itemName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
,price DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL
,dateSold DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO tbl_sales VALUES
(1,'soap',20.00,'2020-06-11'),
(2,'candy',2.00,'2020-07-07'),
(3,'beer',63.00,'2020-08-07');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl_expenses;

CREATE TABLE tbl_expenses
(expenseID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,itemName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL 
,price DECIMAL(5,2) 
,dateBuy DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO tbl_expenses VALUES
(1,'paper',10.00,'2020-06-07'),
(2,'pen',5.00,'2020-07-11'),
(3,'chalk',2.00,'2020-08-07');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m') ym
     , ABS(SUM(price)) total
  FROM 
     ( SELECT salesID ID,itemName,price,dateSold date FROM tbl_sales
       UNION ALL
       SELECT expenseID,itemName,-price,dateBuy FROM tbl_expenses
     ) x
 GROUP
    BY ym;
```

| ym | total |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-06 | 10.00 |
| 2020-07 | 3.00 |
| 2020-08 | 61.00 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qt11CXYPMGJjUuX3c4ySwz/0)